# cypress how to verify all dropdown items without selecting any item

Tags: javascript, dropdown, cypress, html-select

Below is my html for a dropdown control:
[image]

I want to verify that drop down has following items: ["5","15","30","45"]

I have written following piece of code:

```
value=["5","15","30","45"]
cy.get(seelctor).invoke('val').should('deep.equal', value)
```

I do not want to select all of these items just want to verify that drop down has them.
Also, My html does not has the value attribute. How do i assert based on text ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The values between tags like `<li>15</li>` are accessed on individual element with `.invoke('text')`.

`invoke('val')` is for `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements.

But if you select multiple elements, the texts will mash together

```
cy.get('li')                  // multiple elements selected
  .invoke('text')             // joins all text together, result is "5153045"
  .should('eq', '5153045')    // passes
```

In your case it's ok, but feels a little clumsy. In another scenario you can get additional white space between texts which makes it harder to compare.

You can use jQuery to extract individual texts, and they can be trimmed to make a better match when extra white-space is present

```
cy.get('li')                                            
  .then($els => Cypress.$.map($els, (el) => el.innerText.trim())) // uses jQuery .map()
  .should(values => {
    expect(values).to.deep.eq(["5","15","30","45"])
  })
```

But if your dropdown items are fetched from an API, you should put as much of the calculation as possible inside the `.should()` callback, because Cypress retries until passing

```
cy.get('li')                                            
  .should($els => {                                              // retries here
    const values = [...$els].map(el => el.innerText.trim())      // uses Array .map()
    expect(values).to.deep.eq(["5","15","30","45"])
  })
```

Comment: Thank you Steve Zodiac for providing an alternative way. Yours and @AlapanDas's solution worked for me.

Comment: Only the first bit of code works for me. If I try the 2nd and 3rd options I get an error that $els is not iterable even though I can see it in the Cypress window as containing an array (Cypress.Chainable<JQuery<any>> in code)

Answer (score 2):

Create a fixture file `data.json` inside `cypress/fixtures` and write:

```
{
"dropdownValues": ["5","15","30","45"]
}
```

Your test will be like:

```
describe('SO Question', function() {
    beforeEach(function() {
        //Load Fixture File
        cy.fixture('data').then(function(testdata) {
            this.testdata = testdata 
        })
    })
    it('Iterate dropdown and validate', function() {
        cy.get(selector).each(($ele, i) => {
            expect($ele).to.have.text(this.testdata.dropdownValues[i])
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: Ahh.. got it. so we don't have a direct function to check the text of all its children. We should iterate through each child element. @AlpanDas Thank you!

Comment: @buckybarns Sorry i am unaware of that.